# How can I perform the equivalent regex searching operation in emacs like vim?

Tags: regex, emacs

I have a file in which hold the contents like below:

```
hello1
hello2
hello3
haha1
haha2
haha3
```

notice that there some regex pattern `hello\d`.
In vim, I can perform a lookup operation by typing `/hello\d` and then typing `n` and `N` to cursor between different matches to review my codes.

I wonder how can perform the same operation in Emacs. `C-r` and `C-s` would not do the work since there is a regex pattern, but if I use `query-replace-regexp`, I could not go over each match by `C-r` or `C-s`. If that's not impossible by raw Emacs setting? How could I do the same thing in Emacs as I do in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isearch-forward-regexp`, which is bound by default to <kbd>C-M-s</kbd>.  (Similarly, `isearch-backward-regexp` is bound to <kbd>C-M-r</kbd>.)

From there you can use <kbd>C-s</kbd> and <kbd>C-r</kbd> to navigate results as usual.

Comment: got it, first time I use C-M-s I input the regex, and the second time, the C-M-s would lead to next match. C-M-s in emacs equal to n in vim, C-M-r in emacs equal to N in vim

Comment: @LiuWeibo note the edit -- you need only `C-s` or `C-r` to *repeat* the search, regardless of how you initiated the search.

Comment: oh, I understood now. As far as I entering the regex, it's not necessary to press the enter key, as vim would require, and I can use C-s and C-r to navigate through the results.  Thank you for your answer ~~